# Can I use .swf files to edit it?

Tags: flash

This is just the first time I'm working on Adobe Flash CS5. I have files in .swf. I want to make some changes on it, Can I do that or Should I ask the designer about the .fla file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure they can be reverse-engineered somehow, but it's definitely easier to ask the designer for the original .fla file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely go to the original creator - cracking a swf will not get you a usable project that can be edited and recompiled esp. by a first-time Flash user. It might not be OK with original creator and might not be legal either.